# Android accessibility font sizes issue in xamarin Entry fields

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When using the android accessibility font sizes issue in xamarin Entry fields. As shown below the 1st image with general font size ( SIZE 3) so the text in the entry fields looks perfectly OK,
[image]
[image]
but what we change the phone font size to 5 the entry file Text cut through the half , As below
[image]
[image]
I have tried with vertical option center, gridhight="*" as well as Auto, no use, the code as below

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid Margin="20,10,20,0" RowSpacing="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label
                Grid.Row="0"
                FontFamily="{StaticResource KhulaRegular}"
                FontSize="14"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                Text="{Translu:Translate SetupDeliveryInfoDetailRecipientPage_Header}"
                TextColor="#334a5e" />

            <!--  Recepient Name  -->
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Spacing="0">
                <Grid
                    Margin="0"
                    Padding="0"
                    RowSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource KhulaRegular}"
                        FontSize="12"
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                        Text="{Translu:Translate SetupDeliveryInfoDetailRecipientPage_ReceipientName}"
                        TextColor="#777777" />

                    <Entry
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource KhulaRegular}"
                        FontSize="16"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        PlaceholderColor="{DynamicResource OverImageTextColor}"
                        Style="{StaticResource SingleLineEntryStyle}"
                        Text="{Binding RecipientName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        TextColor="#334a5e" />

                    <local:RoundedLabel
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsRecipientNameVisible}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ValidationEntryErrorStyle}"
                        Text="{Translu:Translate SetupDeliveryInfoDetailRecipientPage_ReceipientNameErrorText}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
```

but if we give fixed height the text will show, but that is not the good way to do XAML coding,  so we have to give height to different font sizes which are impossible, is there any way that we can fix the entry filed text to see in an increase of font size in the phone , thank you in advanced for your support

Comment: Try not to use `FontFamily`. I used the default font, which still displays fully when the device font size changes.Maybe it's because of the different fonts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your help ,  I want to use this custom font with font size change . so any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Different fonts have different effects, and I haven't found a good way to do that exactly.